# Angular Spring boot war deployment in tomcat is giving 403

Tags: angular, spring-boot, tomcat, deployment

I know that this combination of technologies and issues have been asked a lot before but I am unable to proceed even after reading most of the related questions.

For angular dist creation
ng build --base-href=/Export_8011/
Copied dist contents into the my src/main/resources folder of spring boot project
Changed pom to package as war and added provided scope for tomcat, extended SpringBootServletInitializer and performed a
mvn clean package
Fired up manager-gui on my tomcat, deployed the created war (this has the same name as the base href used in the ng build step, Export_8011)
War was deployed successfully
Now when I access http://localhost:8080/Export_8011 I am getting this :
[image]

this is my POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.abc</groupId>
<artifactId>Export</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>Export</name>
<description>Export project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>Export_8011</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>war</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceIncludes>WEB-INF/**,META-INF/**</warSourceIncludes>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <warSourceDirectory>target/classes/static/</warSourceDirectory>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>WEB-INF/**</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>war</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

thank you in advance

**EDIT**

this is my web Config :

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedMethods("*")
            .allowedOrigins("*");
}

@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
}

}
```

and this is my Security Config

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private final UserService userDetailsService;
private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

public WebSecurity(UserService userDetailsService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


    http
            .cors().and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(SecurityConstants.SIGN_UP_URL)
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilter(getAuthenticationFilter())
            .addFilter(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}


protected AuthenticationFilter getAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
    final AuthenticationFilter filter = new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager());
    filter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/users/login");
    return filter;
}


@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
}


}
```

Comment: Have u also added @Configuration to route requests to index.html for angular to serve? Also have u configured spring-security to allow access?

Comment: @KNeerajLal I have added my web config and security Config you can see that I allow access to all to avoid cors policy

Comment: Seems like you are requiring authorization headers for resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it.
the problem as I said was in my security config so I have to allow access to root and all file .js and .css by adding this to my authorizeRequests :
**this is my new Config :**

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


    http
        .cors().and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/","/assets/**","**.js","**.css")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .addFilter(getAuthenticationFilter())
        .addFilter(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you will have to add a **catch all** configuration. Here is an example,

```java
@Configuration
public class CatchAllConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        // Map "/"
        registry.addViewController("/")
                .setViewName("forward:/index.html");

        // Map "/word", "/word/word", and "/word/word/word" - except for anything starting with "/api/..." or ending with
        // a file extension like ".js" - to index.html. By doing this, the client receives and routes the url. It also
        // allows client-side URLs to be bookmarked.

        // Single directory level - no need to exclude "api"
        registry.addViewController("/{x:^(?!api$)[\\w\\-]+}")
                .setViewName("forward:/index.html");
        // Multi-level directory path, need to exclude "api" on the first part of the path
        registry.addViewController("/{x:^(?!api$).*$}/**/{y:[\\w\\-]+}")
                .setViewName("forward:/index.html");
    }
}
```

Comment: I try it but it gives me the same problem. but in my opinion I think it's an issue related to my security settings because the status 403 means that my request was blocked by spring security